# Using a possessive apostrophe with an initialism

Tags: punctuation, possessives, apostrophe, initialisms

Should you write "some of the UK's longest tunnels..." or "some of the UKs longest tunnels..."?

Comment: Are you asking about the apostrophe or the capitalization?

Comment: When downvoting or voting to close it is good practice to add a comment specifying why, at least for politeness.

Comment: @ShaughnMcGurk I've edited the question to make it clearer; if I've obscured your original intent, feel free to explain.

Comment: I down voted and voted to close because the question title is about possessive apostrophe, and the question was not, although now it seems to be.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what the question here is, so I'm closing this pending clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

When an initialism is made possessive, it is treated as any other word.  Also, never change the capitalization of an initialism. *UK's* is correct:

> some of the UK's longest tunnels